# WinSCP Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond

Tags: .net, powershell, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

WinSCP version used 5.13.3

I have a PowerShell script that does sftp files to a remote server.

Intermittently I get:

> Timeout waiting for WinSCP to respond

Tried setting `SessionOptions.Timeout` property, which did not help either ...any leads?

Session log....says below...

> . 2019-12-19 11:30:20.325 Opening remote file.
>   > 2019-12-19 11:30:20.325 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 117, Number: 515
>   < 2019-12-19 11:30:22.341 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 515
>   > 2019-12-19 11:30:22.341 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 32764, Number: 1030
>   . 2019-12-19 11:30:45.810 Waiting for dispatching send buffer timed out, asking user what to do.
>   . 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825 Asking user:
>   . 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825 **Host is not communicating for 15 seconds.
>   . 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825
>   . 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825 Wait for another 15 seconds?** ()
>   < 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825 Script: Host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds.
>   < 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825 Still waiting...
>   < 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825 Note: If the problem repeats, try turning off 'Optimize connection buffer size'.
>   < 2019-12-19 11:30:45.825 Warning: Aborting this operation will close connection!

Comment: Please post a debug log file (`Session.DebugLogPath`) from both the session that work and the session that fails.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl , I have just enabled the logging, will share once I see the error.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I updated my post will the log ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off Optimize connection buffer size worked for my case.
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings

Answer (score 0):

In advanced > connection turning off optimize connection buffer size or increase server response timeout for example 9999.